# Why django developers removed TEMPLATE_DIRS from settings.py?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-settings, django-1.6

In django 1.6, there is no TEMPLATE_DIRS in settings.py, why did the developers remove it ?

Answer (score 0):

Not Removed as u can see in here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#template-dirs

Answer (score -1):

Because the default value is fine to get started. The decision was taken that the automatically-created settings.py should only contain the things you actually need to configure in order to start working. The default template dirs work fine for most people, and you rarely need to change them. If you *do* actually need to do so, then go ahead: the setting still exists, and you can override it as you like.